# Calling generic methods of objects of type dynamic

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I am trying to write a method that accepts as a parameter any `IEnumerable<T>`; and call it from code where `T` will not be known until runtime.

I could write it as a generic method and then invoke it with reflection when I want to use it, but for a variety of reasons I decided to use type dynamic. However when I passed in a strongly typed collection output from an Entity Framework function import (a `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>`) and tried to access the Count() method, it threw an exception to the effect that `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>` didn't have a Count() method, which is not the case.

I've worked around this by limiting my interaction with the object to a foreach statement, thus making the compiler figure out how to enumerate it, so it's not a problem. I'm more interested in understanding why I can't do this. My guess is that it's either that Count() is a method on a base class or interface and therefore not accessible for some reason, or that the compiler usually translates calls to Count() to `Count<T>` during compilation and can't do so in this case? Help appreciated.

Edit: I feel like it's probably the case that the compiler is not translating the non-generic `Count()` into a generic `Count<T>`. When you call `Count()` on an `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` you are actually calling `Count<T>()`, it's just syntactic sugar that the compiler takes care of. I think it's probably not making the same translation of `Count()` to `Count<T>()` at runtime. It would be nice to get confirmation of this because this is a pretty annoying limitation of use of generics with type dynamic if so.

Also edited to add code:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by user code    HResult=-2146233088
>   Message='System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' does not contain a definition for 'Count'
>   Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
>   StackTrace:
>   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
>   at MyNamespace.HtmlHelpers.RenderTable(Object list, String id, String cssClass) in [snip]

And an example of the code that throws the exception:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderTable(dynamic list, string id, string cssClass)
{
    int x = list.Count();
    ........
    ........
}
```

Comment: whats the actual error message.  you aren't doing us a favor by trying to paraphrase

Comment: Wrt "will not be known until runtime": At the usage-site, T *must* be resolved to a type at compile time (or itself be a generic type parameter).

Comment: @user2864740 That isn't really the case. Generic methods can be invoked on arbitrary types at runtime using reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `list.Count()` gives a runtime error when `list` is a `dynamic` is that `Count` is an extension method - `Enumerable.Count<T>` - and extension methods can only be discovered at compile time. (Somebody correct me if I'm wrong on this - this is my understanding.)

Before getting the direct answer to your question, take a look at this little toy program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> a = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);
            IEnumerable b = a;
            IEnumerable<double> c = b.SelectTimesPi();
            foreach (var x in c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<double> SelectTimesPi(this IEnumerable source)
        {
            return source
                .Cast<dynamic>()
                .Select(x => Math.PI * x)
                .Cast<double>();
        }
    }
}
```

Its output is the following.

```
3.14159265358979
6.28318530717959
9.42477796076938
```

The `SelectTimesPi` extension method takes any `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is only known at runtime, and then manipulates its elements as `dynamic` values. The `source` could be `IEnumerable<byte>`, `IEnumerable<short>`, `IEnumerable<float>`, etc.

You could of course do the same thing with a non-extension method, like you asked. I just used that as the example since it looks like your aim is to ultimately create an extension method.

The trick is in the use of `Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>` on an `IEnumerable`.

Back to your original question. All you have to do is make your `RenderTable` method take the `list` as an `IEnumerable` instead of a `dynamic`, then use `Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>`.

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderTable(IEnumerable list, string id, string cssClass)
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> dynamicList = list.Cast<dynamic>();
    int x = dynamicList.Count();
    ...
}
```

Now the call to `Count` is *not* dynamically dispatched, so the extension method will work fine.

In summary:

```
IEnumerable<int> x = ...;
(x as IEnumerable).Cast<dynamic>().Count(); // does work
(x as dynamic).Count(); // does not work
```

Comment: Cute. I realised that the answer for me is even simpler; I'd forgotten that `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so I can just cast my result sets down to `IEnumerable` and throw them around like that. I'm using reflection on the items anyway so there's no need for type dynamic.

Your post is a nice demo, but I won't mark it as an answer as I'm still curious what the explanation for the exception I saw is.

Comment: @user3746897 This is the explanation for the exception. You're trying to dynamically call an extension method. That won't work, because the instance your `list` variable is pointing to *does not have* a `Count` method. Also, the LINQ methods are only defined on generic `IEnumerable<T>`, so you actually can't just call `Count` on an `IEnumerable`. `Enumerable.Cast` and `Enumerable.OfType` are the only two extension methods on `IEnumerable`.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771364/use-of-extension-methods-using-a-dynamic-variable-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be demonstrated with this small program:

```
using System;

namespace SO24255725
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static int Count(this Program a)
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }


    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Program test = new Program();
            PrintCount(test);
        }

        static void PrintCount(dynamic data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is why:

> The dynamic feature cannot bind arbitrarily at runtime to extension
>   methods because the extension method feature is defined to be scoped
>   only to the 'using's of the compilation unit. At runtime, the 'using'
>   information is gone, so the runtime binder cannot resolve the
>   extension method. This is by design...

Source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771364/use-of-extension-methods-using-a-dynamic-variable-doesnt-work

You did not list the "variety of reasons" of why you decided to use dynamic. May be you should not.